# Dispatch message properly UART

Tags: c++, serial-port, uart, mbed

In my code, I have a serial interrupt that triggers when an event (receiving) occurs. In that, I'm saving the data to buffer and with that, sending the buffer to analyze. The problem I have is, how can I fetch the whole response from the serial port to buffer not just one char at the time?

```
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);
Serial sim(GSM_TX_PIN, GSM_RX_PIN);
count =0;
int main()
{
    sim.attach(&dispatchMsg); //Interrupt handler
    wait(1);

    sim.puts("AT\r\n");

    while()
    {
    }
}

void dispatchMsg()
{
    while(sim.readable()){
        char c = sim.getc();
        buffer[count++] = c;
    } 

    //Here i want to wait for whole response from uart instead i fetch only one char
    void analyzeString(buffer);
}

void analyzeString(char* str)
{            
    /*Do something with the str ...*/         
}
```

Example of incoming responses from sim module:

```
AT
OK
ERROR
+CMGI: ...
```

IDE: mbed

Comment: You can't, really. The UART is too stupid to know what a message is. Best you can do is read out of the UART and pass the characters up to a handler that DOES know what a message is. That handler assembles the message for you  (`std::stringstream` is often helpful here) and passes the assembled message on to something else that knows how to parse messages.

Comment: Note: Get out of the interrupt as fast as you can. Avoid doing any message processing during the interrupt. Do what you can to get the data and get out. Stuff the data into a buffer and set a flag that the `main` loop can read so that it knows there is data to be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ATCmdParser](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/platform/ATCmdParser.h) instead of using raw UART. It already does parsing and buffering for you and is part of Mbed OS 5.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have tried with AT Parser but in the end, I figured it out with Adafruit_Fona Library.

Answer (score 1):

To specifically answer your question, you can check when the received buffer is ready(assuming after receiving "\r\n") for analysis:

```
void dispatchMsg()
{
    static int end_char_count = 0;
    while(sim.readable() && end_char_count < 2){
        char c = sim.getc();
        buffer[count++] = c;
        if(c == '\r' || c == '\n')
            end_char_count++;
        else
            end_char_count = 0;
    } 

    //Here i want to wait for whole response from uart instead i fetch only one char
    if(end_char_count == 2)
    {
        end_char_count = 0;
        analyzeString(buffer);
    }
}
```

However, an interrupt handler should be as quick as possible. Otherwise you may start loosing serial data. Generally processing of the data is delegated to the main thread by leaving data in a buffer/queue and main thread polling for the complete of data. UART drivers and ATCmdParser will do it for you as pointed out by @Jan.

Also, if your question is in context of AT commands then it is possible to receive a multi line answer. In that case your analyzeString() has to do some similar buffering until all expected lines are received. Or decode the response as each line is received.